# iOS RestKit custom error handling

Tags: ios, restkit

I'm trying to find a best way of processing results from API. I went through number of tutorials and guides, but none of them were able to provide me guidance how to correctly process custom errors from API.

The best tutorial I found I followed is this one, but I'm still missing the final piece - error processing:

http://www.nsscreencast.com/episodes/51-intro-to-restkit-mapping

Every API function (GET, POST, PUT and DELETE) in our project returns following JSON output:

```
{result: TRUE/FALSE, data:(string, object or array), error_message:"custom error message"}
```

If result is TRUE, data is returned, otherwise error_message is returned. Every request returns code 200 or 404 as a result, but 404 is only returned if API URL was not found. Here is an example of getting cities in specific country. If I try to get cities from a country which is not in the database, API returns FALSE and custom error message.

The question is, how can I handle this situation?

**LocalityCity.h**

```
@interface LocalityCity : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) int idCity;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;

@end
```

**RestMappingProvider.m**

```
+ (RKObjectMapping *)localityCityMapping
{
    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[LocalityCity class]];

    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                  @"id": @"idCity",
                                                  @"name": @"name",
                                                  }];

    return mapping;
}
```

**RestDescriptorProvider.m**

```
+ (void)localityCityDescriptor
{
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptorGet =
    [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[RestMappingProvider localityCityMapping]
                                                 method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                            pathPattern:@"/api/locality/cities/:id"
                                                keyPath:nil
                                            statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptorGet];
}
```

**LocalityCityViewController.m**

```
@interface CityViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *cities;

@end

@implementation CityViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[RestDescriptorProvider localityCityDescriptor];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObject:self.cities
                                          path:@"/api/locality/cities/2"
                                    parameters:nil
                                       success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                           NSLog(@"OK");
                                       } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                           NSLog(@"Error");
                                       }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally the web service would use one of the HTTP status codes to tell the client there was a problem, then you could use a response descriptor specifically to handle that and an `NSError`.

You can use a dynamic mping which checks the result type and determines how to process the result. Depending on the flag value a different mapping will be applied to create a different result class with the appropriate details for you to use. Exactly how you handle that is up to you, either with a class type check, or perhaps having your model objects return a 'success' flag, perhaps supported by a protocol.

Comment: Thank you Wain. I tried the dynamic mapping and it didn't work (RestKit was not able to map the result from post request to another object other than the one that initiate the request). However, I changed API to return 4** codes instead of 200 when error occurs and I think it's best solution.